# Expanding $(2^b-1)\cdot(1+2^b+2^{2b}+ \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

Can someone please explain to me how the following works (primarily interested in an explanation of the second step when $2^b$ is expanded?

I understand how each series cancels out to equal $2^n-1$ at the end.

$$\begin{align*}
xy&=(2^b-1) \cdot (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
&=2^b \cdot (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b}) - (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
&=(2^b + 2^{2b} + 2^{3b} + \cdots + 2^{ab})-(1+2^b+2^{2b}+ \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
&=2^{ab}-1\\
&=2^n-1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: It isn't factored out. Instead, the term $(2^b-1)$ is distributed over the other term.

Comment: They've expanded the first product to give the difference in the 3rd line. Most of the terms cancel and leave $2^{ab} -1$ over. Then they've defined $ab = n$.

Comment: The first factor in the third line is wrong: it should be $$2^b+2^{2b}+2^{3b}+\cdots+2^{ab}\;.$$ Once you get it right, you see what @Ed_4434 explained: most of the terms cancel out.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think that's what OP intended but forgot braces in the exponent

Comment: @Ed_4434: I expect that you’re right, since there was originally a clear typo in one of the exponents in the title as well, but I don’t like to fix possible genuine mistakes until it’s confirmed that they’re typos.

Comment: Typo fixed. @Ed_4434

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon Not quite; almost all of the exponents on the third line have the same problem!

Comment: @Ed_4434 My mistake. That should be all of them. Still learning how to format everything.

Comment: What's to explain?  You did a good job explaining it yourself.  And you say you understand the final result.  So ... what more do you need?

Comment: point of terminology.  You are not factoring.  You are doing the opposite of factoring.  You are multiplying multiple factors  in to get a single expression.  Factoring is taking a single express and factoring multiple factors out to a product of multiple factors.

Comment: Um... $2^b(1 + 2^b + 2^{2b}..... + 2^{(a-1)b}) $ $= 2^b*1 + 2^b*2^b + 2^b*2^{2b} + ....... + 2^b2^{(a-1)b} $ $= 2^b + 2^{b+b} + 2^{b + 2b} + .... + 2^{b + (a-1)b} $ $= 2^b + 2^{2b} + 2^{3b} + ..... + 2^{ab}$.  Is that enough detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps understand this better if you set $t=2^b$, so your product becomes
$$
(t-1)(1+t+t^2+\dots+t^{a-1})
$$
Distribute:
$$
t(1+t+t^2+\dots+t^{a-1})-(1+t+t^2+\dots+t^{a-1})
$$
Push $t$ in the first term inside the parenthesis:
$$
(t+t^2+t^3+\dots+t^{a})-(1+t+t^2+\dots+t^{a-1})
$$
Regroup:
$$
\underbrace{(t+t^2+t^3+\dots+t^{a-1})+t^{a}}_{t+t^2+t^3+\dots+t^{a}}
\;
\underbrace{{}-1-(t+t^2+\dots+t^{a-1})}_{-(1+t+t^2+\dots+t^{a-1})}
$$
Cancel the opposite terms:
$$
t^a-1
$$
Substitute back $t=2^b$:
$$
(2^b)^a-1=2^{ab}-1
$$
Conclusion:
$$
(2^b-1)(1+2^b+2^{2b}+ \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})=2^{ab}-1
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
xy&=(2^b-1) \cdot (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
&=2^b \cdot (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b}) - (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
&=(2^b + 2^{2b} + 2^{3b} + \cdots + 2^{ab})-(1+2^b+2^{2b}+ \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
&= \left[2^{ab} - 1\right] + \left[(2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{
(a-1)b})-(2^b+2^{2b}+ \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b}) \right]\\
&= 2^{ab} - 1 +(2^b - 2^b) + (2^{2b} - 2^{2b}) + \cdots \\
&=2^{ab}-1\\
&=2^n-1
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align*}
xy&=(2^b-1) \cdot (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
\end{align*}$

**Let $A = (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})$ so**

**$xy = (2^b-1)A = 2^b*A - A$.  Let's continue...**

$\begin{align*}
&=2^b \cdot (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b}) - (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
\end{align*}$

**Note: $2^b \cdot (1 + 2^b + 2^{2b} + \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})=2^b*1 + 2^b2^b + ...+2^b2^{(a-1)b}$**

**$= 2^b +2^{2b} + .... + 2^{ab}$.  And that's pretty much all the detail I can think to provide.  Continue...**

$\begin{align*}
&=(2^b + 2^{2b} + 2^{3b} + \cdots + 2^{ab})-(1+2^b+2^{2b}+ \cdots + 2^{(a-1)b})\\
&=2^{ab}-1\\
&=2^n-1
\end{align*}$